# Emacs Auctex change default View command

Tags: macos, emacs, preview, viewer, auctex

I need help using the `View` command in Auctex running in emacs. This is essential for viewing pdfs and without it I can not make TeX documents. In my emacs file I have the following (which was created by M-x customize-variable):

```
(custom-set-variables                                                                    
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.                                            
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.                         
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.                                
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.                                    
 '(TeX-view-program-list (quote (("Preview" "\"open -a Preview.app %o\""))))
```

Now I open up a `.tex` document and enter `C-c C-c` (I have already compiled):

Emacs gives: `Command: (default View)`

I hit enter

Emacs gives this default command: `View command: dvi2tty -q -w 132`

I hit enter and emacs says: `View: done.` but displays nothing in a pdf reader!

`dvi2tty` is intended for text only devices, and the command actually creates a new buffer in emacs which attempts to display the pdf file (it is very messy). Anyway, if I replace `dvi2tty -q -w 132` with `open -a Preview.app %o' (I am running Mac os X 10.8.4 and Preview is the name of the default pdf reader) then Preview opens the pdf!

1. How do I change the default `View command` from `dvi2tty -q -w 132` to `open -a Preview.app %o`?

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got lucky and found a solution!

Follow these steps

1. `M-x customize-variable`
2. Emacs gives: `Customize variable:` Enter: `TeX-command-list`
3. Search for `View` (enter `C-s` and then type `View)
4. Emacs will take you to the view command where you can enter text.

It will look something like this (after Command there will be a place for text entry):

```
[INS] [DEL] Name: View                                                                                 
            Command: open -a Preview.app %s.pdf                                                        
            How: [Value Menu] TeX-run-command                                                          
            Create a process for NAME using COMMAND to process FILE. More                              
            Prompt: [Toggle]  on (non-nil)                                                             
            Modes: [Value Menu] All                                                                    
            Menu elements:                                                                             
            [INS] [DEL] Lisp expression: :help                                                         
            [INS] [DEL] Lisp expression: "Run Text viewer"
```

Change the text after `Command:` to whatever you need. This will automatically change your `~/.emacs` file.